# How to edit variable's content?

Tags: variables

For example, I've used `redir` command to redirect command output to register a.
Register a contains several lines of text.
How to remove a line from register a or substitute a string from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The register a is stored in variable `@a`. If you need a little bit more control you can access the register through the functions `setreg()` and `getreg()`.

Substitution can be accomplished though the function `substitute()`, filtering can be done with `filter()` (but you may need to convert the string into a list first with `split(str, "\n")`)...

Comment: You can also use `execute()` as an alternative to `:redir`, e.g. `let foo = execute('ls')`. See `:h execute()`. `execute()` requires Vim 7.4.2008+

Answer (score 1):

You can also make edits interactively by:

- pasting the register contents into your buffer: `"ap`
- editing with whatever Vim commands you like
- and then yanking or deleting back into the register with e.g. `"adip`